# unknown behavior of grails while adding role to existing user

Tags: grails, spring-security

Whenever i add role to my existing `User` its not functioning.

There are no errors in logs, I also accessed my controller with try catch but no luck.

Here is my `addRole` closure:

```
def addRole = {
     def role = Role.get(params.addRoleAutoComplete_id)
     def user = User.get(params.id)
     if (!role) {
         flash.message = "Select role from list"
     } else {
     try{
        UserRole.create( user,  role)
     }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace()}
    }
 redirect  action:'edit', id:user.id
}
```

using Grails 2.3, grails spring security plugin and STS 3.2

Here is My UserRole.Groovy:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

User user
Role role

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
        return false
    }

    other.user?.id == user?.id &&
        other.role?.id == role?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (user) builder.append(user.id)
    if (role) builder.append(role.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}


static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
    new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
}

static boolean remove(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
    UserRole instance = UserRole.findByUserAndRole(user, role)
    if (!instance) {
        return false
    }

    instance.delete(flush: true)
    true
}


static mapping = {
    id composite: ['role', 'user']
    version false
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `UserRole.create( user,  role)`, try calling `new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(insert: true, failOnError: true)` and see what is happening

Comment: thanks for your response but this has no luck. `UserRole.create( user, role)` was working fine with my code while I was using grail 1.3.6. Recently I upgraded my app to Grail 2.3 and facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks mate I made a change in your suggestion  `new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` and now its working fine but can any one tell me the cause why `UserRole.create( user, role)` is not working.

Comment: What does your UserRole domain look like?

Comment: Hi Gregg, Unable to post my UserRole.groovy in comment. How could I post here?

Comment: You can just edit your post. And add the code.